# In python how do i selectively combine/ print output 4 lists

Tags: python-3.x

***in python v3 how do i get the prices of items based on  given conditions

l3 -> (color  price ) & l4->(articles base price )  & l1=(color name) & l2= (article name)
Ans::: should be like***

### *orange - chair = 740, red - chair = 930... so on*

```
l1= ['orange', 'red', 'black', 'blue' , 'white']
l2 = [ 'chair', 'table' , 'cup']                                                                            
l3 = [240,430,650,700,900]
l4 = [500, 1000, 40]
```

Comment: This will be a lot easier if you change your `list`s into [`dict`s](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  Then it's as simple as `price = colors[color_name] + articles[article_name]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to have those Outputs separated by a ", " or a "\n".

But here it is:

```py
l1 = ['orange', 'red', 'black', 'blue' , 'white']
l2 = ['chair', 'table' , 'cup']                                                                            
l3 = [240, 430, 650, 700, 900]
l4 = [500, 1000, 40]

for i,elem2 in enumerate(l2):
    for j,elem1 in enumerate(l1):
        print(f"{elem1}-{elem2} = {l3[j]+l4[i]}" , end = ', ') # Separated by ", "
        #print(f"{elem1}-{elem2} = {l3[j]+l4[i]}") # In differents lines
```

You can also use `itertools` to simplify these kind of problems like that:

```py
import itertools

l1 = ['orange', 'red', 'black', 'blue' , 'white']
l2 = ['chair', 'table' , 'cup']
l3 = [240, 430, 650, 700, 900]
l4 = [500, 1000, 40]

for (j, elem2),(i, elem1) in itertools.product(enumerate(l2),enumerate(l1)):
    print(f"{elem1}-{elem2} = {l3[j]+l4[i]}" , end = ', ')
```